# Ensuring Laravel 5.1 uses TLS 1.2 with AWS S3 bucket

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3, tls1.2

AWS s3 bucket requires tls1.2

I got an email from AWS telling me that there are objects in my s3 bucket that have been accessible using tls version less than tls 1.2 and I have to update my clients.
I have a legacy laravel 5.1 project running on nginx/php5.6 fpm and installed aws-sdk 3.9.11 where i use the s3::storage and s3->put to let users upload files.

I checked my nginx configurations and removed tls1.0 and 1.1 and kept the tls1.2 available only but I don't know if I have to change something to force the s3 connection from my laravel to the s3 bucket to use tls1.2

I also added these configuration to my laravel project in app/filesystems.php

```
        's3' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key' => 'myKey',
            'secret' => 'MySecret',
            'region' => 'eu-central-1',
            'bucket' => 'myBucketName',
            'options' => [
                'http' => [
                    'verify' => true,
                    'curl' => [
                        CURLOPT_SSLVERSION => CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2,
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
```

This is my upload controller where I'm adding files to the s3

```
    function uploadCustomersCsv() {
    $maxsize = 1000000;

        $s3 = \Storage::disk(\Config::get('filesystems.default'));
        $destdir = 'OmegaCloud/'. \Session::get('custid') .'/'. 'importTemplates/uploads';
        if (!$s3->exists($destdir)) {
            $s3->makeDirectory($destdir);
        }
        if (Request::hasFile('image')) {
            $file = Request::file('image');
            $size = $file->getSize();
            $mime = $file->getMimeType();
            $ext = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $type = Array(1 => 'csv');
            if (!(in_array($ext, $type))) {
                return response()->json(array(
                            'error' => 'Unsupported invoice file'
                ));
            }
            $destname = Str::slug(str_replace(".$ext", '', $file->getClientOriginalName()));
            $destfull = $destdir . '/' . $destname . '.' . $ext;
            $filecounter = 1;
            $duplicate = null;
            while ($s3->exists($destfull)) {
                $duplicate = $destname . '_' . $filecounter++;
                $destfull = $destdir . '/' . $duplicate . '.' . $ext;
            }
            if ($duplicate !== null) {
                $destname = $duplicate;
            }
           
            if ($s3->put($destdir .'/'. $destname .'.'. $ext, file_get_contents($file), 'public')) {
                return response()->json(array(
                            'path' => 'mys3path/' .$destdir .'/'. $destname .'.'. $ext,
                            'meta' => array(
                                'size' => $size,
                                'mime' => $mime,
                                'filename' => $destname .'.'. $ext
                            )
                ));
            } else {
                return response()->json('failed to move file' . $destfull, 501);
            }
        } else {
            return response()->json('NoFileException', 501);
        }
    }
```

Adding these options in s3 array in filesystems to force tls1.2, I want to ask if it works with my php5.6 and laravel 5.1 or at least how to know if it's now using the tls1.2

Thank you

Comment: This is a server configuration issue, nothing to do with client code. If the server only offers TLS 1.2, the client has to use it.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, my server I updated my nginx configuration and enabled only tls1.2 but what If my php code is sending somewhere the file using tls1.1 ? i think I have to change also the outgoing outbound connections from the server to the s3, here I don't know how

Comment: Your question is very unclear, I think you may be confused about the roles played by various parts. Nginx handles the HTTP connections with clients. PHP code running on the server has nothing to do with TLS. For PHP code connecting to another server using TLS 1.2, the PHP version matters less than the version of OpenSSL it was compiled with. If your PHP was compiled with OpenSSL 1.0.1 or higher you're fine, and there's no need to change any configuration. Best available security will always be used. That said, PHP 5.6 is ancient and dangerous and should be updated.

Comment: Yes my openSSL is higher than 1.0.1 I thank you for your answer since I think the clients are using my website and uploading files with tls1.0 on windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I received the exact email from AWS. They gave some connection logs. upon investigation, it was because my end-user was using somehow an old version of Windows 10 and TLSv1. and not my server or Laravel.

I inspected this using the user-agent string from the connection logs that AWS gave me.

For more, you can watch this AWS stream:

https://www.twitch.tv/videos/1783721977

They explain the client's programs that can be using old TLSv1.

I hope this helps.